# Vue.js - while loop alternative

Tags: javascript, vue.js, while-loop

I want to print a component as many times as an int.
Something like:

```
x = 5;
while(x >= 5)
{
<component></component>
x++;
}
```

I know about v-for loop but I would like to print with a number not with an array. Is it possible?

Comment: `v-for` with a range? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-a-Range `v-for="x in 5"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v-for` can be also used in a range:

```js
new Vue({
     el:"#app"
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 40%!important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
     <ul>
          <li v-for="index in 5" :key="index">{{index}}</li>
     </ul>
</div>
```